# SQL select query to return only if a record has a field of a single value

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have built my query here thus far:

```
SELECT POLICYNUMBER, FPLAN, FEFFYY, FEFFMM, FEFFDD, FINSTP, CLIENTNUM, FIRSTNAME, 
MIDNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE FROM PFCASBENE 
INNER JOIN CMRELATN ON POLICYNUMBER = KEYFIELD1 
INNER JOIN CMPERSON ON CLIENTNUM = CLIENTID
WHERE FPSFLG='I' OR FPSFLG='P' ORDER BY CLIENTNUM ASC
```

The FINSTP field has a single character for an insurance type code.

EDIT:  POLICYNUMBER, FPLAN, FEFFYY, FEFFMM, FEFFDD, FINSTP are fields in PFCASBENE
  CLIENTNUM is a field in CMRELATN and FIRSTNAME, 
    MIDNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE are from CMPERSON.  I should have said that before.

I want to return the results if the client **only** has policies that the FINSTP='F'.  If they have other policies that have FINSTP = 'X', 'V', etc, then I don't want any of the clients records in the results.

this query returns multiple rows since a client can have multiple policies.  I can get results if I put FINSTP='F' in the WHERE clause, but that's not what I want.  That returns all that are 'F'.  I'm not sure what else I need to add to the where clause to tune this query to what I need it to do.

This is for a DB2 on an AS/400 system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- Josh

Comment: Which table does that field (FINSTP) come from?  And which RDBMS?

Comment: @sgeddes Sorry the FINSTP comes from the table PFCASBENE.  Edited the question for which RDBMS / System this is for.

Comment: Josh, I am thinking there may be a better performing answer.  Do you know how to run Visual Explain from a Run SQL Statement window in System i Navigator, so that you will be able to compare?

Comment: @warrent yes I do.  I was planning on doing that as soon as I catch a break here and get some time. This query takes an exceedingly long time to run (+20)min, which I believe is due to the inner query.  I broke the query out into 2 separate lists In java and compared them to each other takes a total of about 30 seconds.  I'm going to run the visual explain shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT POLICYNUMBER, FPLAN, FEFFYY, FEFFMM, FEFFDD, FINSTP, CLIENTNUM, FIRSTNAME, 
MIDNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE FROM PFCASBENE 
INNER JOIN CMRELATN ON POLICYNUMBER = KEYFIELD1 
INNER JOIN CMPERSON ON CLIENTNUM = CLIENTID
WHERE (FPSFLG='I' OR FPSFLG='P') AND CLIENTNUM not in (
SELECT CLIENTNUM FROM PFCASBENE 
INNER JOIN CMRELATN ON POLICYNUMBER = KEYFIELD1 
INNER JOIN CMPERSON ON CLIENTNUM = CLIENTID
WHERE FINSTP <> 'F')
ORDER BY CLIENTNUM ASC
```

Sub select says, return all clients records with FINSTP not equal to F and then exclude that clients results, even if they have a FINSTP of F (but due to other FINSTP values, the entire client is expunged.  But if they ONLY have FINSTP of F then that client would not be excluded.

I'm basing this off of the OP stating:

I want to return the results if the client ***only*** has policies that the FINSTP='F'. If they have other policies that have FINSTP = 'X', 'V', etc, then I don't want any of the clients records in the results.

Comment: yes this is very close to what I need.  POLICYNUMBER, FPLAN, FEFFYY, FEFFMM, FEFFDD, FINSTP are fields in PFCASBENE.  
  CLIENTNUM is a field in CMRELATN.   FIRSTNAME, 
    MIDNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE are from CMPERSON.  I should have said that before.  Yes if they only have policies where the FINSTP is 'F' then I want to see them, if they have 'F' and another type, or just another type, I don't want them in the results.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT POLICYNUMBER, FPLAN, FEFFYY, FEFFMM, FEFFDD, FINSTP, CLIENTNUM, FIRSTNAME, 
MIDNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE
FROM PFCASBENE 
JOIN CMRELATN ON POLICYNUMBER = KEYFIELD1 
JOIN CMPERSON ON CLIENTNUM = CLIENTID
WHERE FPSFLG IN ('I', 'P')
AND CLIENTNUM NOT IN (
    SELECT CLIENTNUM
    FROM PFCASBENE 
    JOIN CMRELATN ON POLICYNUMBER = KEYFIELD1 
    JOIN CMPERSON ON CLIENTNUM = CLIENTID
    WHERE FINSTP != 'F'
)
ORDER BY CLIENTNUM ASC
```

I improved your main query by using `FPSFLG IN ('I', 'P')` rather than `FPSFLG 'I' OR FPSFLG = 'P'`, which apart from being neater, is more likely to use an index (if one exists on that column).

I would have coded this as a left join, but I have no idea which columns come from which tables - too much guess work, and this query will work.

Comment: This is helpful as switching the where clause over to being able to use an index.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your key is the `POLICYNUMBER`, and `FINSTP` is a field on `PFCASBENE`;

```
SELECT 
    POLICYNUMBER, FPLAN, FEFFYY, FEFFMM, FEFFDD, FINSTP, CLIENTNUM, FIRSTNAME, 
    MIDNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE 
FROM PFCASBENE 
INNER JOIN CMRELATN ON POLICYNUMBER = KEYFIELD1 
INNER JOIN CMPERSON ON CLIENTNUM = CLIENTID
WHERE 
    (FPSFLG='I' OR FPSFLG='P')
AND POLICYNUMBER NOT IN(--Policies other than F. You don't want them.
    SELECT POLICYNUMBER FROM PFCASBENE 
    WHERE FINSTP <> 'F'
)
ORDER BY CLIENTNUM ASC
```